# What is it for a function with two argument places to be continuous in its first argument?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm reading a paper where the authors describe a function $f(x, y)$ that is 'continuous in its first argument'. Specifically, $x \in [0, 1]$ while $y \in \{0, 1\}$. I can't find the definition for a function that is continuous in its first argument, though I expect it is obvious. Can anyone help?

Comment: It means that the function $\phi_y(x) = f(x,y)$ is continuous (for fixed $y$).

Answer (score 3):

All it means is the following. For fixed $y$, define $g_y(x):=f(x,y)$. That $g_y$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will mean that for any sequence $x_n$, which converges to some point $x$, you will have that $f(x_n, y) $ converges to  $f(x, y)$, but not necessarily the same holds for a sequence $y_n$ and $f(x, y_n) $. Is that what you were looking for?